# Remove unnecessary margins from a custom dialog

Tags: android

I have a problem that I am designing a custom dialog for this. I am creating a xml for this as Framelayout is the root layout, and another framelayout with a gray background image is used for the contents, in which I have added a textview and two buttons Ok and Cancel and use all of this through `dialog.setContentView(desired Xml Resource);`
But when I generate that particular dialog then it shows extra spaces from each side, or we can say that extra margins are there but I don't know how it will removed? Please review the image attached with this question and suggest me the right solution.

**Xml Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:background="@drawable/dialog_box_bg" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="189dp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv_LogoutDialog_Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:text="Are you sure want to logout?" android:textSize="20dip" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"></TextView>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_LogoutDialog_Cancel" android:background="@drawable/dialog_cancel_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_width="120dip" android:layout_height="42dip" android:layout_gravity="bottom|left" android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"></Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_LogoutDialog_Ok"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_ok_btn_hover"
    android:layout_width="120dip"
    android:layout_height="42dip" android:layout_marginLeft="180dip" android:layout_gravity="bottom|right" android:layout_marginBottom="15dip" android:layout_marginRight="20dip"></Button>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Code:**

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case 0:
            dialog = new Dialog(HomeScreenActivity.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logoutdialog);
            btn_cancel = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_LogoutDialog_Cancel);
            btn_ok = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_LogoutDialog_Ok);

            btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    dismissDialog(0);

                }
            });

            btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreenActivity.this,LoginScreen.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        return dialog;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.logoutdialog);
```

use

```
LayoutInflater class to set Dialog content view
```

Here is link ([Check](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2011/07/create-custom-dialog-using.html)) you can get the idea May this helps you.

Comment: Put the xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
in inner frame layout and remove the outer layout then check.

Comment: Nopes, result still remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Change it by adding a parameter **false** like in the code below.

```
dialog.customView(R.layout.dialog_blueprint, false)
```

The second argument (false) is **wrapTheDialogBoxInScrollView**. If the content in the dialog box is small and does not require a ScrollView set it to false.